# How many and/or what criteria does CfsSubsetEvaluator use in selecting features in each step of cross-validation while doing feature selection?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, feature-selection

I am quite new to `WEKA`, and I have a dataset of `111 cases` with `109 attributes`. I am using feature selection tab in WEKA with `CfsSubsetEval` and `BestFirst search method` for `feature selection`. I am using `leave-one-out cross-validation`.

So, how many features does WEKA pick or what is the stopping criteria for number of features this method selects in each step of cross-validation

Thanks,

Gopi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CfsSubsetEval` algorithm is searching for a subset of features that work well together (have low correlation between the features and a high correlation to the target label). The score of the subset is called merit (you can see it in the output).

The `BestFirst` search won't allow you to determine the number of features to select. However, you can use other methods such as the `GreedyStepWise` or using `InformationGain`/`GainRatio` algorithms with `Ranker`and define the size of the feature set.

Another option you can use to influence the size of the set is the direction of the search (forward, backward...).

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I have one more doubt: in `WEKA` for `BestFirst` search method `parameters` it says _**searchTermination -- Specify the number of consecutive non-improving nodes to allow before terminating the search**_. Is this like the stopping criteria for the number of features in each step of the cross-validation. Can you please explain

Comment: Like I said, the algorithm calculates the "merit" score of each subset. The BestFirst is almost greedy. The parameter determines the number of tries to find a better sub-set if the previous ones did not improve the score. When it reaches a subset it cannot improve- it will stop and return the best set found.